Lagrangian relaxation (Pytorch implementation) with inequality constraints does not converge
I'm using PyTorch to solve an optimization problem with Lagrangian relaxation. I think my implementation is correct but it just does not converge and I do not why. I'm unsure what the problem is and what I lost or forgot.
import torch

# The optimization variable
x = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0], requires_grad=True)
# The Lagrange multipliers
lambda_ = torch.ones(4, requires_grad=False) * 10

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([x], lr=0.01)

# The objective function is c^T x
# It is a linear function, x_1 + 2 x_2
c = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0])
# The constraints are A x <= b
# The constraints are:
# x_1 + x_2 <= 2
# x_1 - x_2 <= 2
# -x_1 + x_2 <= 2
# -x_1 - x_2 <= 2
radius = 2.0
A = torch.tensor([[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, 1.0], [-1.0, -1.0]])
b = torch.tensor([radius, radius, radius, radius])


def lagrangian(x, lambda_):
    obj = torch.dot(c, x)
    constraints = torch.matmul(A, x) - b
    lagrangian_value = obj + torch.dot(lambda_, constraints)
    return lagrangian_value, constraints


num_epochs = 1000
alpha = 0.1  # The learning rate for the Lagrange multipliers
for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    L, g = lagrangian(x, lambda_)
    L.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    L, g = lagrangian(x, lambda_)
    L.backward()
    lambda_ = torch.clamp(lambda_ + alpha * g.detach(), min=0)

print(f"Final solution: x = {x.detach().numpy()}, lambda = {lambda_.numpy()}")

Obviously, this problem's solution is simple but the algorithm cannot handle it.
I have tried different learning rates but it does not work and the solution oscillates up and down. So, please give me some suggestions on how to resolve this issue.
